# TcPdf not showing same signature name which send in function

Tags: php, symfony, tcpdf

I am using TcPdf for signature. I have issue relate signature name. I send `sign1` name in `addEmptySignatureAppearance()` but the name display in pdf like: `/T (þÿ s i g n 1 [ 0 0 2 ])`

In code:

```
$pdf->addEmptySignatureAppearance(20, 27, 175, 70, 30, 'sign1');
$pdf->addEmptySignatureAppearance(20, 110, 175, 70, 30, 'sign2');
```

The pdf open in text editor as a text document for see the below code:

```
/T (þÿ s i g n 1 [ 0 0 1 ])
/T (þÿ s i g n 2 [ 0 0 2 ])
```

but I want result like :

```
/T (sign1)
/T (sign2)
```

Dose any way to do it.

Comment: addEmptySignatureAppearance is a function to allow the user to digitally sign, where should you see the name?

Comment: The name is 6th paremate of `addEmptySignatureAppearance` function. like: `addEmptySignatureAppearance(x,y,w,h,page,name) `

Comment: Which sense have see label like a text? if that is for digital sign?